# DBeaver SQL Editor: how to search/replace in only the current window?

Tags: editor, dbeaver

In the DBeaver SQL Editor, is there a way to search and replace only in the current script window? It seems like this should be simple and obvious, but to me it's not.

My search dialog looks like the below. I don't see how I can restrict the scope to just the current window (assuming I have multiple scripts open in different tabs). I also don't understand why the "Resource in active editor" option is disabled. I've explored underneath the "Working set", but there too it's not clear how to specify only the current window.

[image: DBeaver search dialog]

I'm running DBeaver v.21.0.1 on Windows 10.

DBeaver's [File Search documentation page](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/File-Search/) does not explain these search scope options.

DBeaver is such a great tool, but sometimes quite obtuse!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried Ctrl-F or "Edit > Find Replace"?
BTW, it took me a little while to figure this out too!

Comment: Ha! Indeed, that does the job. Too bad it does not appear as an option underneath the "Search" menu. And in the manual, `Ctrl+F` is documented for "Data Search" https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-Search/, but not for the SQL editor itself. ;-(